# Can I solve a system of high-degree polynomial equations with the Gröbner basis method?

Tags: polynomials, groebner-basis

I have two equations, two unknown (ISP, ch) and one parameter ($n_C$). My aim is to find the values of the unknown according to the parameter. The original rational equations are here :
https://framabin.org/p/?5a4a682c865ca030#GHL5aWQ6hPZ6m0csuQwQ7GSj15UWJxliKIohqkj21gY=

I converted them in polynomial, you can look at them here in a $ \LaTeX$ format:
https://v1.overleaf.com/23360386gqfrrchwvyxx

I used singular through sagemath to get the Gröbner basis. Nonetheless, singular crashes to get the variety of the ideal. But

The code I used in sagemath :

```
pch_simple = final2_simple.simplify_rational().rhs().denominator() * ch - final2_simple.simplify_rational().rhs().numerator()  #polynom for ch
pisp_simple = final1_simple.simplify_rational().rhs().denominator() * ISP - final1_simple.simplify_rational().rhs().numerator()  #polynom for ch
Rsimple = PolynomialRing(FractionField(PolynomialRing(QQ, names='n_C')), names='ISP,ch') #Multivariate Polynomial Ring in ISP, ch over Fraction Field of Univariate Polynomial Ring in n_C over Rational Field
plist_simple = [Rsimple(pch_simple),Rsimple(pisp_simple)] #list (system) of my polynomials
I_simple = ideal(plist_simple) #the ideal of the system of polynomials
G_simple = I_simple.groebner_basis() #the Groebner basis
len(G_simple) #I have three equations in my Groebner basis
I_simple.dimension() #0, the ideal is zero-dimensional
I_simple.variety() #stuck
```

I think the problem come from the high degree of my second equation ('pisp_simple'). In this equation, ISP is degree two but ch is degree 15. In the first equation ('pch_simple'), ISP is degree one and ch is degree three.

Must I concede my polynomial is impossible to solve or does alternative methods exist to solve my nonlinear system of equations composed by two polynomials ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to solve polynomials exactly. That is only possible for fourth-order on down in the first place. For higher-order polynomials, in general, you're going to have to use a numerical method.

Comment: I was aiming to solve the polynomial exactly according to my parameter $n_C$. I wanted to plot my variables according the values of my parameter. I was inspired by the article Kubler, F., & Schmedders, K. (2010). Tackling Multiplicity of Equilibria with Gröbner Bases. Operations Research, 58(4-part-2), 1037–1050. https://doi.org/10.1287/opre.1100.0819 . But in my case, the only possibility is to solve numerically, isn't it ?

Comment: @Adrian Keister has pointed to the problem. If you have, say a 15th degree in one variable and a 2nd degree in another variable, it is likely that it is not the 15th degree that will occur but even the 30th degree, or the 60th degree or wathever... The probability is 0% that your system is solvable formally. You have to turn (as said by the same Adrian Keister) to a numerical method.

Comment: It is would be much better to use [mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to express your equations.  At a glance the ones you link to (at a site which pops up a modal dialog asking for donations) are rational in the variable $ch$ and not polynomial.  A $\LaTeX$ version of the equations (preferably using single character variables) would clarify this point.

Comment: @JeanMarie: You may be a little overly pessimistic.  Even a 30th degree polynomial might have a lower degree factor.  But it appears to me the equations are rational rather than polynomial, at least in one of the two variables.

Comment: @harmath My little experience with formal methods, even with moderate degree polynomials, is that, yes you can get sometimes one, or two very low degree  factors (first degree, quadratic) but that the remaining factors remains with a large degree and thus intractable by formal methods

Comment: Do you know that there is a term (elimination, very common in the XIXth century) and an associated function ("Eliminate" in Mathematica, I imagine you have a similar function with Sage) associated with your issue which is "eliminate nc between such and such equations ? An alternative for using Eliminate is using the resultant, which is present in CASs as a very useful function ("Resultant" in Mathematica) but I do not advise you to use it here (too much preparatory work !)

Comment: @hardmath, I added a $\LaTex$ file with the polynomials equation. I converted the equations rational in variable $\mathit{ch}$ to get polynomial equations. You can look the overleaf here : https://v1.overleaf.com/23360386gqfrrchwvyxx .

Comment: @JeanMarie, There is the same command Eliminate in Maxima I can use in sagemath. Nonetheless, I don't understand why I should eliminate $n_C$. Could you explain me your intuition, please ?

Comment: Here is a geometrical look giving a certain intuition. Let $x=ISP, y=ch, z=nc$. We can think to the equ. as the implicit equations of two surfaces $f(x,y,z)$=0 and $g(x,y,z)=0$, that are intersecting (it is wishable !) giving a space curve (courbe gauche) (C). The geometrical view of the elimination of variable (= parameter) $z$ is plainly the proj. onto plane x0y of (C), possibly providing a better understanding. Looking for a parametric description $x=x(z), y=y(z)$ can lead to a failure because  you may have two points $(x,y,z_1) \neq(x,y,z_2)$ of (C) projected on the same $(x,y)$.

Comment: I think your equations are awefully complicated. Can't simplify them ? Besides, by mere curiosity, may I ask you the applicative domain you are in ?

Comment: Then, I have to solve $\mathit{ISP}$ according to $\mathit{ch}$, haven't I ? My field is financial economics. I study the phenomenon of 'rational destabilization' on the commodity markets. It is when, rational traders use the existence of other traders following trends to give an impulse which is self-fuelfilling (a bubble for example). I know the model becomes quickly messy but it is one of the rare which allows to study the feedback from futures market to spot market. $\mathit{ISP}$ and  $\mathit{ch}$ are covariances. The first one is important because it gives the destabilizing impulse.

Comment: And $n_C$ is the weight of the trend-followers.